# How to see permisisons basing on user, not files/folders

Tags: permissions, samba

I have samba share setup and permissions to files and folders are given through setfacl then a copy of the whole command

```
setfacl -m user:*username*:rwx /mnt/working/*MainFolder*/Engineering dept/OPERATED PROPERTIES/Texas/Martin County/Test_#1_Well_File.xls
```

is saved in the `setperms.sh` folder. If setfacl commands are ran without being saved into the `setperms.sh` folder, there is not record of the permission granted to certain users.

Is there a CLI or GUI way to see what a user has access to? not RWX to file and folders through `ls -l` or `getfacl <file or folders name>` but a way to type a users name and see, as a tree, the entire directory access for that particular users?

Comment: Run `sudo -u username find / 2>/dev/null`, I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the command you are looking for to find all folders that belong to a specific user would be:

```
sudo find / -type d -uid $(id -u <username>) 2>/dev/null > filename.txt
```

*Let's break down that command.*

`sudo` means to run the command as an elevated user.

`find` is the actual command we are running, and of course, we are looking for something.  Running `man find` will bring up the man pages for the `find` command showing more options available.

`/` is the starting point where `find` is going to start looking.  `find` is a recursive application meaning that it will look through all folders.

`-type d` means that we want it to only return directories.  `-type f` would mean files.

`-uid $(id -u <username>)` is we want the UID number of the user from the sub-shell command of `id -u <username>`.  Enclosing the command in the `$()` is the sub-shell allowing us to grab the output of the command.  If you ran the command by itself as `id -u root` it will return a `0` as that is the UID of the root user.  So, the option itself would look like `-uid 0` as that is what the sub-shell command would return.

`2>/dev/null` means to suppress error messages and send them to `/dev/null` which means you will not see the output of the errors.

`> filename.txt` is where we want to send the output to instead of the screen.  This could also be replaced with `| tee -a filename.txt` which will allow you to see the output on the screen as well as creating a `filename.txt` containing the same stuff you saw on the screen.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much Terrance, i think you nail it! now, can i ask you to edit your command to specify only folders and not files [to prevent 100,000 lines] and to send output to a txt file so i can import to word or any other program..

Comment: @sogtech You're very welcome!  =)

Comment: well thank you again, but this part 2>/dev/null is the one that i don't want to screw up! How do i tell the command to send the output to a file that i can open with a txt editor later?? txs!

Comment: @sogtech the 2>/dev/null is used to suppress errors where folders may not be read by the command.

Comment: @sogtech I did also add the output to a file that works fine.  =)

Comment: Terrance, when i run the command as you posted i can see the output running across the screen but then the Null folder [i believe] is blank, what i might doing worng??

Comment: @sogtech The 2>/dev/null has to have the 2 in front of it.  At the end after null, you add the `> filename.txt` where filename is what you want your output to be named.

Comment: @sogtech By the way, /dev/null will always be empty.  It is where you send stuff that you don't want to keep at all, like error messages that are not needed.

Comment: ok, got it now, it is ...find / -type d -uid $(id -u <username>) 2>/dev/null > filename.txt... Fantastic!!

Comment: @sogtech Glad you got it working.  =)

Comment: as you see i am new to Linux and i would like to understand the command that i am running so i can work on different variations. 
can you breakdown the command so i can change it as needed??

- i can still see files and i would like to only have the list of folders that my permissions allow me to access
- after looking closely i cant see some folders that i know i can access, is there a way to allow this command to access all and output my complete list of files/folders access??
- i tried to run the command for other users but i get nothing, is there something that i am missing? 

txs!

Comment: @sogtech Updated my answer with explanations.  Hope this helps!